# Django object in view?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm using Django templates with HTML/JS to show the results of simulations in python/Anaconda. The simulation depends on the setting of different parameters. After the initial data is loaded (from files) and visualized by the first call of the page, the parameters can be chosen in textfields/dropdowns in the template. An AJAX-request sends the parameter to the view and retrieves an array with the results.
Do I need to send all the initial data with the requests everytime, or is it possible to store it in, for example, an attribute of an object in the view? Are examples avaiable?

Comment: You can store data in the [session object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) between requests.

Comment: Where are the files (initial data) being loaded from? Are they coming from server side, or from the user (client side)?

Comment: From the server side

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set up some kind of socket (for instance using Django Channels) you'll have to resend the entire request data on each request. This doesn't seem to be much of a problem for your use case, though.

Comment: A representative amount of data to do the simulation on has a size of 9710484 bytes. It would be nice to somehow store this in the view without the need to transfer it everytime the settings change.